# John Deere GX85 rear engine rider

Tags: lawnmower, john-deere

I have an John Deere GX85 rear engine rider that the back wheels slant inward toward the body. Took a back wheel off and feel some play or movement. No transmission problems at this point. Ideas would be helpful. Thanks for your reply

Comment: where did you feel the play? How did you test? How much slant?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! I was also wondering, what exactly is your question?

Comment: How about a photo?